# Silverlight 5: GraphicsDevice is always null

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am developing 3D applications using Silverlight 5.0.

For me `System.Windows.Graphics.GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice` is always showing `null`.

Here is my code

```
private void DrawingSurface_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderMode != RenderMode.Hardware)
        {
            if (GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderModeReason == RenderModeReason.SecurityBlocked)
            {
                throw new  Exception();
            }
        }


        GraphicsDevice device = System.Windows.Graphics.GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice;

        _vertexBuffer = StreamHelper.ToMesh(device, "cube.obj");

        _effect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice);
        _effect.Texture = StreamHelper.ToTexture2D(device, "Tulips.jpg");
        _effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        _effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
        _effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
        _effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 1.667f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    }
```

Can anybody help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you allowed 3D Graphics? If not run Silverlight.Configuration.exe (for me it is in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.0.61118.0\") and select the Permissions tab. There allow the 3D Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check for some of the other GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderModeReason values.  As discussed a bit more in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/10/18/some-reasons-why-my-3d-is-not-working-with-silverlight-5.aspx